Изменить текущее описание тревоги "Больше не воспроизводится"
Когда я отмечаю вопрос тревогой по причине:
Необходимо улучшить → Специфичная для сообщества причина → <Пункт 1>
Я вижу текст:

На enSO описание тревоги звучит иначе:

Перевод:

Не воспроизводится или вызвано опечаткой
Хотя подобные вопросы могут быть по теме, этот вопрос был решён способом, который вряд ли поможет будущим читателям.

Лично меня слово "больше" запутывает. А вас?

Предлагаю убрать слово "больше" в тексте тревоги и изменить фрагмент описания тревоги на следующий:

Вопрос вызван опечаткой или невоспроизводимой проблемой. <...>


Меня тоже путает. Я за изменение.
